# how to use jquery to add css based on screen width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I like to write a code that will add `margin:0 auto;` to a div.

```
var bestsize = 1445;
 var width = $('.first-image').width();
if( width >= bestsize){
    $('.first-image').css({margin : '0 auto'});

}
else {
    $('.first-image').css({margin :' 0 0 -1px 0'});

}
```

first-image is a div that has a background image

This is what I have, I think it should work. but maybe i am not stating it correctly. currently nothing will happen. I have feeling that I do not use width the proper way. Can someone give me an idea if this solution is no good?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: i presume that .first-image is a img tag.. if so, are you waiting until the image has loaded before getting the width of it? then you need to check the window.load event

Comment: what do you mean nothing will happen ? doesn't on of the two `css` calls execute?

Comment: The div has a background image, yes the css calls do not execute sorry i am unclear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why do you need to do it from java-script instead of using CSS media queries?

```
.first-image{
  margin: 0 0 -1px 0;
}

@media (min-width: 1445px) {
  .first-image{
    margin : 0 auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First can you see anything in your debug console ?

Is jQuery loaded ?

Try this:

You need to wrap it around

`$(document).ready(function()({});`

to load the function when page is ready

and/or

`$(window).resize(function(){});`

to load the function on page resize.

Also I would use `$('.first-image').css('margin', '0 auto');`

Comment: hello, thank you for your response. I do have the $(document).ready but i also have other code in there which is why i did not include it here. IF i use this then i do not need if statement? Thank you!

Comment: you do but I think the CSS way is probably best